# Placing a layout of items, not shown buttonBar

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, mobile, buttonbar

I have some problems with the marking layout, I have not shown the buttonBar, although it is in the code xml. 
Please solve my problem.

This is my code:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageQuote"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Description"
    android:id="@+id/descriptionOfQuote"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageQuote"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:textSize="22dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonBar"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/arrow_left"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_copy"
        android:src="@drawable/copy"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_share"
        android:src="@drawable/share"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/arrow_right"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vomd4.png)

How to make that buttonBar was at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: what do you want to achieve, exactly? Are you saying that you don't want two button bars?

Comment: I want to buttonBar was at the bottom. In my code it is, but the screen does not have.

Answer (score 0):

I have two clues that can solve your problem:

1) make LinearLayout orientation horizontal:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/buttonBar"
android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:foregroundGravity="center"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
```

2) I am not sure but there could be a problem with height of children of buttonBar, try to set it as width:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:id="@+id/arrow_left"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"/>
```

I actually do not have Android Studio to check if my answer is correct, sorry for that :(

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not help me.